# How to pick words in a log file using shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to pick words start with "Approved by" and end with after "AAAA" letters . here is log file.

```
Test worker] INFO cyyom.bghhht.gsghhj.dijjkkgital.dggcf.applicationservice.service.RequestServiceImpl - Approved List : 
[AssignAccountApplicationRequestDto [status=true, requestId=1, backendData=BackendPopupDto [userID=0, companyId=0, ApplicationId=0, 
userType=Test, corpId=0, revenueOwner=notnull, requestedDate=null]]] , Rejected List : [AssignAccountApplicationRequestDto [status=false, requestId=11, backendData=null]]
Approved by ha:////4P4ei7QWIY1VDT3ygY1geg0Q82Jj2AqLzGAAAAmh+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/
JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAyxEgY+/
dLi1CL99OKCxJTczDwAUT2GdsMAAAAXLPortal Administrator
```

I tried

```
awk -F'=' '/^Approved by / && NF>=2{print $NF}' log
```

expected output

```
XLPortal Administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
match($0,/AAAA[ =].*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/AAAA[ =]+/,"=",val)
  print val
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: It doesn't work. because some times there is no "=" sign in log file. I need to pick words after "AAAA". I changed the log file in here according to my new output

Comment: @Zero5, will there be always space `AAAA`?

Comment: @Zero5, Please do check my edited program and let me know if this helps you, cheers.

Comment: after "AAAA" (dLi1CL99OKCxJTczDwAUT2GdsMAAAAXLPortal Administrator) it comes the user name I needed. in here it name is XLPortal Adminstrator. I want to pick words after "AAAA". hope you got my point

Comment: your edited answer doesn't work. yes there always be space after "AAAA" as swdAAAARavinder Singh. I need to pick "Ravinder Singh" as answer

Comment: @Zero5, could you please try `awk 'match($0,/AAAA[ =].*|AAAA[^ ]*$/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/AAAA[ =]+/,"=",val);print val}'  Input_file` once and let me know if this helps you?